# Access vanilla JS var inside Angular or React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs

I have searched extensively on this forum and other platforms, but unfortunately, I have not been able to find a solution. My requirement is as follows: the Front End application (written in Angular/React) needs to be able to connect to different APIs, such as development (dev), staging (stg), quality assurance (qa), and production (prod). This functionality should be adjustable within the client application itself, without the need to rebuild the application each time when change is made in URL pointing.

I have a constants.js as:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "url": "http://www.development.com/api/v1/xxx"
    },
    "stg": {
        "url": "http://www.stagging.com/api/v1/xxx"
    },
    "dev": {
        "url": "http://www.producion.com/api/v1/xxx"
    }
}
```

and want to access the constats.js file.

Please help or guide me on how may I achieve my target.

Sorry for my English. English is not my native language.

Comment: Just... do so? Both React and Angular are _themselves_ written in plain JS, and run in the same JS context as everything else on your page. They just _manage_ their own data in their own ways. So if you need to access your `constants.js`, just add an `import { ... } from "./constants.js";` to whatever needs it?

Answer (score 0):

To access vanilla/plain JS with Angular JS follow the below steps:

```
Include Vanilla JavaScript: You can include your vanilla JavaScript code in the Angular project by adding it to your project's assets folder

a. Assets Folder:

src/
├── app/
├── assets/
│   └── vanilla-script.js
└── index.html

b. index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="assets/vanilla-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

c. Accessing Variable:

    
// vanilla-script.js
var myVanillaVariable = 'Hello from Vanilla JS!';

// Angular Component app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var myVanillaVariable: any; // Declare the variable from the script

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: '<p>{{ myAngularVariable }}</p>',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myAngularVariable: string;

  constructor() {
    this.myAngularVariable = ''; // Initialize in the constructor
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myAngularVariable = myVanillaVariable;
  }
}
```

Please let me knoe if I may improve this answer

Thanks,
Dinesh Gupta